# Conda create: prevent install of certain package during environment creation

Tags: conda

I am working through various kinks trying to build an environment capable of running a common set of packages, however I am having a bit of trouble controlling the solve. I find myself wanting to be able to *exclude* certain packages from being installed. That is, I want the solve to exclude a configuration if it involves installing that package, and to keep looking for a different solution.

For a little context, I am finding that the solution conda is coming up with involves installing both libgcc and libgcc-ng, and I think this is causing some problems, and I'd like to prevent conda from considering options that include libgcc-ng which I am pretty sure *shouldn't* be absolutely necessary.

How can I achieve this as part of my "conda create" command?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a custom package that uses [a `run_constrained` requirement](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#run-constrained). A simple reference example would be the `nomkl` package (see [the Conda Forge meta.yaml](https://github.com/conda-forge/nomkl-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml)), which blocks the installation of the `mkl` package by including:

```yaml
requirements:
  run_constrained:
    - mkl <0.a0
```

That is, this option requires that *were `mkl` installed*, it must abide by this constraint. And since no version of `mkl` can ever satisfy this constraint, it effectively prunes all solutions that would include it.

Comment: Hmm, cool, but quite a bit of overhead required. Might be the only option though?

Comment: @BenFarmer seems like it. If you could specify it as a feature, consider adding it as an issue to the repo.